# Bash script : Loop

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to have your inputs on the following script logic.

So we have a script which upgrades (in terms of RPMs) depending on the customised OS version.

So we have these versions in place ---   1.1.5,1.1.8,1.2.1,1.2.2

Now we have a small script written for updated from 1.1.5 to 1.1.8. So this script checks the third octet(to say) and then does the required job.
Now we have to modify this script to go for a change in 2nd and 3rd octet as well. So the script should handle the upgrade of 1.1.5 to 1.2.2.
So the logic had to be modified. So far we have used the following logic.

```
for (( j=`$installed_ver_nr + 1`; j<=$target_ver_nr; j++ ))
do
    for k in $list_of_reqd_RPMs_to_install
    do
        if [ $j -lt $target_ver_nr ]; then
            rpm -ivh $k
        fi
    done
done
```

Now the above script handles the upgrade from 1.1.5-> 1.1.8 but not 1.2.2. 
Your inputs in this case will help. 
Thanx.

Comment: `for((j=installed_ver_nr+1; i<target_ver_nr; j++))`: everything inside the `((...))` is already an arithmetic expression, so there is no need to invoke `expr` (which is also made obsolete by `$((installed_ver_nr+1))` in the general case).

Comment: Is this script sequentially installing all RPMs for the given set, in order, from the current version up to the target version? If so, why on earth are you doing that?